# Retrieve currently displayed backdrop

Tags: chromecast

I noticed that in the Chromecast app, it displays the current backdrop active on the device.  I would like to achieve the same result in my own app.

Does anyone know of any documentation that exists for how to interrogate a chromecast for its currently displayed backdrop?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to do that, due to a number of reasons, one being privacy issues.